# SeeTest developer tools or equivalent for CRUDing cookies

Tags: seetest

My team uses SeeTest for our mobile app.

Typically in web view we can set cookie values within dev tools console like:

```
document.cookie = "feature='on'"
```

However, when testing with SeeTest how do you manipulate cookie data (and use dev tools)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the documentation? https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies

```
driver.manage().addCookie( new Cookie("feature", "on") )
```

Comment: Hello @Neils Thank you for the response. I have tried that but was wondering if there is a form of "dev tools" for mobile app testing within SeeTest. That's all.

Comment: Ah I guess i partly misunderstand the question. Have you tried remote debugging? https://experitest.com/mobile-app-testing/app-dev-debug-anywhere/

Comment: Ah yes, I think remote debugging is the tool! Thanks Niels!